# merge columns in sql then identify the source column

Tags: sql-server

I want to have a query for this table that will merge the data of each two column into 1 (Material1 + Material2, Quantity1 + Quantity2, Time1 + Time2) and another row to identify the material if it was a Material1 or Material2.

Input data:

[image]

Desired output:

[image: desired Output table]

I have tried:

```
SELECT Material1 as Material 
FROM [test] 
UNION all 
SELECT Material2 
FROM [test]

SELECT [Quantity1] as Quantity 
FROM [test] 
Union all 
Select Quantity2 
FROM [test] 
ORDER BY Quantity1
```

but it turns out to be in two tables..

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please have a look at this [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your "merge columns" is misleading. You want to `Pivot` your data.

Comment: Yah I want to put the data of the two columns in just one, not CONCAT.. sorry for misleading you...

Comment: SELECT Material1 as Material
FROM [test]
UNION all
SELECT Material2
FROM [test]SELECT [Quantity1] as Quantity
FROM [test]
Union all
Select Quantity2
FROM [test]
ORDER BY Quantity1 but it turns out to be in two tables..

Comment: Oh yah sorry,,, my bad...

Comment: Any chance you can change the table design? You have violated 1NF here with repeating groups. Consider how difficult this would be if you need to add Material3. All of your queries would have to be fixed. Ideally those would be rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
select 'Material1' as Name
      ,Material1 as Material
      ,Quantity1 as Quantity
      ,Time1 as [Time]
from   [test]

union all

select 'Material2' as Name
      ,Material2 as Material
      ,Quantity2 as Quantity
      ,Time2 as [Time]
from   [test]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot got it!!